# Why am I getting red lines when simulating this circuit?

Tags: pspice, orcad

I am trying to simulate this circuit but I end up getting red lines on the Pspice simulation, what could have caused this error.

The circuit I am trying to emulate in pspice,

[image: Given circuit]

Here is the circuit diagram I implemented

[image: circuit]

And here is the output/ pspice simulation.

[image: Simulation result]

My question is why am I getting those red lines in the pspice output?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://education.ema-eda.com/iTrain/PSpice163/PSpice_lesson17.html) the double red line in a digital trace signifies an unknown or undeterminable logic state:

[image]

(Source: http://education.ema-eda.com/iTrain/PSpice163/PSpice_lesson17.html )

An example of an unknown state is the initial state of a flip-flop.

I'm not sure, however, why it is happening in your circuit.

Here is a video which shows how to explicitly program the waveforms for each clock:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9k1ca-IaxLM&t=11m50s

(Link starts the video at 11:50)